# Get Protection type of Object Variable in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm building a class. I intend for this class to be a sort of master parent class for a lot of API and database interactions later on.

Assume it looks something like this

```
class api_controller{
    public $method = 'get';
    private $table;
    protected $table_id_column;
    //Rest of code is really not needed
}
```

**I was wondering if it was possible, from within PHP, to figure out if a variable is `public`,`private`, or `protected` if given the name? If it is, I had planned to use it as a checking station to make sure that no child methods alter data they've been restricted from accessing via an inherited method.**

I had googled my question and came up with a lot of `get_object_vars()` vs `get_class_vars()` discussions, as well as a *great* many discussions about the difference between private, protected, and public. From my search of Object/Class functions through the PHP database, I didn't see anything that immediately jumped out at me as my answer.

I was thinking that it may have to be a try/catch statement done by accessing the variable and seeing if it throws an error (which would let me know if it was public/private), but I'm unsure of how to determine past that point. Even then, this method would have to be a member of the parent class, so it would have access to all of its own private variables.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Don't start writing code which tries to protect against itself. Just declare your methods and properties appropriately as `protected` or `private`, then regular code is prevented from accessing those properties to begin with (which is the whole point).

Comment: I can't really discuss the entirety of the project at length, this was more a curiousity(sp?) than anything else. I had already planned a way to code it, but if this was doable then I could *theoretically* change a few lines of code here and there.

Answer (score 1):

Use ***[Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php)***:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('api_controller');
$property = $class->getProperty('method');
// then you could check by
// there are also methods of isProtected, isPublic, etc...
if ($property->isPrivate()) {
  // ..
}
```